# Киррилица в phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

когда я записываю с помощю INSERT INTO кириллицу то у меня записывает в бд каракули но когда я вывожу эти каракули на сайт то все нормально обычний руский, а когда я в базу данных с сайта phpmyadmin ввожу кириллицу то на сайте выводит каракули, можно ли исправить мою проблему и как сделать что бы на сайте phpmyadmin можно было прочитать
Пример каракуль на сайте phpmyadmin: РњР°РєСЃРёРј

 Пример каракуль на моем сайте: ����

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всего лишь надо в bd.php или config.php прописать:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите в конфигурационный файл MySQL - my.cnf, в секцию mysqld следующие параметры.

```
[mysqld]
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci'
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
default-character-set=utf8
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

Укажите для базы и таблиц кодировку utf8_general_ci. Перезапустите MySQL.

Укажите для сайта кодировку UTF-8

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: А где можно найти этот файл (my.cnf)?

Comment: Нашел,вставил, перезапустил сервер, а сервер не запускаеться

Comment: Посмотрите лог MySQL. Попробуйте закомментировать последние 2 строки.